# Why VisualStateManager is not working?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Here's a UserControl:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Border x:Name="Border1" Background="Green">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello, World!"></TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Grid>

<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup >
        <VisualState x:Name="ExampleState">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border1">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red">
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

And somewhere in codebehind:

```
    public DialerView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;

        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "ExampleState", false);
    }
```

Please, could you explain, why Border1 doesn't change  it's color to Red?

Comment: put your VSM inside the Grid above your Border, and use a `ColorAnimation` instead of a `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, VSM should be in a Grid and everything will work now.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question and solved it with the help of official documents:
[UWP:VisualStateManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.VisualStateManager)

I gonna to pick the saying from the document:

> Control authors or app developers add VisualStateGroup object elements
>   to the root element of a control template definition in XAML, using
>   the VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups attached property.

So,i think what cause your *VisualStateManager* not working is that your VisualStateManager's part should be put into the hero element(except Page, I guess) scope (Maybe it's Grid or Maybe it's RelativePanel or else)